# Web Services accepting SQL as input

Tags: sql, database, web-services, api, architecture

I find a lot of my web services are there to provide CRUD access to some relational data. For example I have concepts such as `users`, `profiles`, and `hosts`, each have properties, and relations between them (`users` have `profiles`, `hosts` belong to `users`, etc).

I'm thinking that the best way to specify what you want is to express it in SQL.

```
select name, profile.name, profile.id from users, profiles order by users.date;
```

What would be a good/feasible/safe approach to make a web service accept input as SQL Queries?

Is there some kind of re-usable SQL parser/engine that I can re-use?

EDIT: I don't mean allowing people direct access to the database. I just mean allowing them to express their needs ("I want all users names, along with the name of their corresponding profile, and the date of its creation, with the number of associated hosts, all sorted by date of last modification") in SQL. It doesn't mean the Web service has to forward the SQL query verbatim to the database.

Thanks

Comment: Write the sql in the web service and pass it parameters.  If someone has an ad hoc select query, use another application.

Comment: Sending a complete SQL query as input to a web service seems like a security nightmare just waiting to happen....... imagine what an attacker could do! **Don't do this!** It might *sound* really smart and tempting at first - but having a separate service layer with its own limitations and checks is a **good thing** - don't break that up by allowing callers to send you arbitrary SQL statements!

Answer (score 3):

**This sounds like a very bad idea.** First, you open up the web service interface to support SQL queries, and in the next step you need to filter out everything that could be harmful - which is a lot in the context of SQL.

Please don't do this. Define what operations your clients need and support exactly these queries. With this approach, you define the SQL queries on the server side, and just pass in parameters from the client. Use input validation and prepared statements to avoid security issues.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a kind of [**domain-specific language**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) that you want to implement and pass to a web service.

Take a look at groovy's capapilities on [how to implement a domain-specific language](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html).

Answer (score 0):

As already stated injecting SQL into a web service is a security issue. But if you REALLY, REALLY need this flexibility you should not be afraid of the effort to write your own interpreter. Then you are able to cut those things out that could make harm to your application.